# Select news posts from a database with a highlighted date posts sorted first

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm building a custom news feed component and am trying to implement the concept of highlighted posts. An example of the table is as follows:

| id | title | content | post_date | highlight_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | ... | `2021-10-01 06:12:00` | `null` |
| 2 | Test 2 | ... | `2021-10-02 08:54:00` | `null` |
| 3 | Test 3 | ... | `2021-10-03 13:52:00` | `2021-11-30 00:00:00` |
| 4 | Test 4 | ... | `2021-10-04 15:32:00` | `null` |

Naturally, when pulling data I'll be ordering by `post_date DESC`, however highlighted posts need to appear at the top, but **only if today's date is before the highlighted date**. If today's date is after the highlighted date, it it should be ignored and appear naturally within the `post_date` sort.

This query below for example won't work, as highlighted posts will always appear first, even after the `highlight_date` has lapsed.

```sql
select * from post
order by post_date desc, highlight_date asc
limit 20
```

While I can separate this into two queries (one for highlighted only and one for regular only), and compound the two in the application, implementing it for use with pagination/infinite scroll will now be difficult as I don't have the benefit of using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in my query.

Using the above example data, I'm trying to build a query where the resulting order will be `[3, 4, 2, 1]` for dates before 2021-11-31, but `[4, 3, 2, 1]` for dates after.

I'm not sure how to go about this in an efficient way, as I'm expecting this table to grow over the years. Any direction or assistance would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Comment: Hi SteppingHat, There is no date: `2021-11-31 00:00:00` ; November is 30 days long

Comment: @sukalogika haha nice :P I didn't copypaste the data from anywhere, I just made up some junk while typing out the question ;)

Comment: Before I know this fact, I thought you inserted not valid data `2021-11-31 00:00:00` and resulted `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in db :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  *,
    COALESCE(highlight_date > NOW(),0) highlight
FROM    post
ORDER
BY  highlight DESC , id DESC
```

My date NOW is `2021-10-01 23:06:00`

**Result when NOW() is lower than highlight_date**
[image: Result-lower]

**Result when NOW() is greather than highlight_date**
[image: Result-greather]

**Explaination:**

`COALESCE` is required for comparing `NULL` data.
Because when `NULL` compared by `date`, the result is `NULL`.
And `0` is Greater than `NULL`

**Wrong Result Without Coalesce:**

```
SELECT  *,
    highlight_date > NOW() highlight
FROM    post
ORDER
BY  highlight DESC , id DESC
```

**Resulted:**
[image: without coalesce]

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT * FROM post
ORDER BY CASE WHEN highlight_date > NOW() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, post_date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6f0bd75bf87f4999d0740c1e0f63e40)

Comment: This one is working and probably faster than mine, because doesnt return 1 extra column.